# OTG read and bypass the cache via storage access framework(SAF)

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

It's my first post in here so please be benevolent and friendly to me.

Hello everyone,

From Android 6, OTG drive is officially supported by Android but not mounted in file system.
It can only be access via Android's unique Storage Access Framework(SAF).
Althought I can get the file permission in Marshmallow by following way.

```
getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri,
Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION |
Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Unfortunately, I just can open file by fdopen successfully, but can not use O_DIRECT to bypass cache.

I also close the file descriptor, then use

```
int open(const char *pathname,int flags, mode_t mode)
```

to open the file again. It return file descriptor equal -1 which indicate open fail.

Could anyone here please point me how to open/write/read file by SAF and bypass the cache?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot use fdopen() and open() as they are for files. Not for a content scheme. Open an input stream to read the contents of the 'file'. You can find examples all over the place.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Actually, I have opened the input stream to read the file.But this is the method for JAVA which can not bypass cache.What I need is read and bypass the cache under SAF.